# KnockoutJS with MVC Partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am having problems persisting data from KO observableArray in a MVC Partialview...

I have a side navigation menu where one of the nodes is dynamically built using KOjs 'foreach', and this navigation menu should persist across the site. The menu is rendered ok on the first View page but when I navigate on other page (clicking on menu option or any way) the dynamic node is empty, although the observableArrays were fetched and loaded with the correct data.

It seems like the navigaition menu (which is a partial view) is not refreshing/reloading to render the menu nodes/options again.

Any help si much appreciated. TIA!

```
self.reports = ko.observableArray([]);
self.reportCategories = ko.observableArray([]);

self.getReports = function () {
    App.Server.get("/.../reports/")
        .then(function (vm) {
            self.reports(vm.reports);
            self.reportCategories(vm.categories);
        });
};

self.init = function () {
    self.getReports();
};

self.init();


<li>
<a class="level1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#report-submenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Reports</a>
<ul class="level1 collapse" id="report-submenu" data-bind="foreach: reportCategories">
    <li>
        <a class="level2 collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="text: label, attr: { href: '#' + value }" 
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
        <ul class="level2 collapse" data-bind="foreach: reports, attr: { id: value }">
            <li data-bind="if: category == $parent.categoryId">
                <a class="level3" data-bind="text: menuName, attr: { href: reportName }"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Here's the other part of the code (a Nancy GET method):

```
Get["/"] = _ =>
{
    var reportModel = new ReportModel();
    var reports = reportService.GetList();
    if (reports != null)
    {
        // Categories
        reportModel.Categories = reports.Select(s => s.Category).Distinct().Select(c => new ReportCategoryModel()
        {
            CategoryId = c,
            Label = c.TrimStart("Reports/".ToCharArray()),
            Value = c.ToLower().Replace('/', '-')
        }).ToList();

        // Reports
        reportModel.Reports = reports.Select(r => new ReportRecord()
        {
            MenuName = r.MenuName,
            ReportName = r.ReportName,
            Category = r.Category,
        }).ToList();
    }

    return Response.AsJson(reportModel);
};
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or some sort? Not sure when/where you are binding. Not seeing how you're passing `vm` into your `GET` other than the reference in the promise.

Comment: Thanks for checking @dward, I've added the GET method where the data is coming from.

Comment: I noticed in your example, you're using a relative path to your endpoint (App.Server.get("`/.../reports/`")). If you navigate to a folder structure nested from your current location, the HTTP call might be failing which causes the list to never render. Also, you may consider caching responses (ie not making another request) if the user's links won't change even with a refresh. You'd have to take a more SPA approach, but worth considering.